# How to use With on previously defined expressions

Tags: functions, core-language

The command `With[{x = 1}, x]` outputs `1`.

The command `t = x; With[{x = 1}, t]` outputs `x`.

I expected this second input to give the same answer. How can I modify my code so it behaves in this way?

Comment: To give you an idea: try `t=x; With[{x=1}, {x, t}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing the behaviour of `With` and `Block`

```
t = x; Block[{x = 1}, t]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Yes, this works better for my more complicated actual situation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
t = x; With[{x = 1}, Evaluate[t]]
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you